# Redirecting linux terminal file data

Tags: linux, input, terminal

I have two files. One is v3in.txt file in which I have the commands to be executed list. In the second file v3out.txt I wish to store the output of each of these commands.

Can some one help me how to use the standard input output stream to achieve this.

**My v3in.txt file contents:**

sudo snmpget -v 3 -l authPriv -a SHA -A "NetMan2019" -x DES -X "ITP201820" -u John 198.51.100.5 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0

sudo snmpget -v 3 -l authPriv -a SHA -A "Net20192020" -x DES -X "TCP201820" -u John 198.51.100.5 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. If you are just wanting to execute the commands in `v3int.txt` and have the output redirected to `v3out.txt`, then you can do `bash v3in.txt 2>&1 > v3out.txt` (or `sh v3in.txt ..`). If you want to run `v3in.txt` as an executable script, simply add `#!/bin/sh` as the 1st line (or `#!/bin/bash` if you are running bash as your shell), make it executable (`chmod +x v3in.txt`) and then run it `./v3in.txt 2>&1 > v3out.txt`.  (though if you make it executable, I would drop the `.txt` extension and just use `v3in` for the name)

Comment: Well, they are SNMP Get commands so the first one- execute the commands in v3int.txt and have the output redirected to v3out.txt will work. However, I am getting permission denied for file v3out.txt when executing the bash command.

Comment: You don't have write permission in the directory you are trying to save the log file in. Either adjust the current directory permissions or redirect the output to your home directory, e.g. `bash v3in.txt 2>&1 > ~/v3out.txt`. The output file with the be under `/home/yourusername/v3out.txt`

Comment: Changed the file permissions and it worked! :) Thank you so much.